# How do i align .pull-right to align text in bootstrap depending the screen width

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to aling to right if the screen is md and if xs i want to center on the screen , can i do that?

I don't know what can i do that

```
enter code here

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 box-header">
<h3 class="box-title">REPORT</h3>  
</div>  
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8  box-header col text-center">
<h4 class="box-title pull-center" >
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i><a href="#">CLICK TO REPORT</a>
</h4>
</div>
```

if the screen is xs i want the text center if not i want to see to the right

Comment: There is no `.pull-*` class in Bootstrap 4. Use flex utilities instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `d-flex` in conjuntion with `justify-content-center` and `justify-content-md-end` classes to approach it. Also note that in **Bootstrap 4** there is no `col-xs-12`, that should be replaced by `col-12`. However it will implicitly take that configuration if you omit it:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-4 box-header">
    <h3 class="box-title">REPORT</h3>  
  </div>

  <div class="col-12 col-md-8 box-header">
    <h4 class="box-title d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md-end">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i>
      <a href="#">CLICK TO REPORT</a>
    </h4>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```